# how to write generic extensions for standard collection types in java?

Tags: java, generics

I am a Java beginner and I am looking for an idiomatic way of writing a function that involves generics. I wrote this helper class (below) that pushes items into a sorted generic collection and I wanted to ask for your feedback. Should I perhaps extends some base class of some collection? Or maybe there is some better approach that follows the Java philosophy?

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class ListExtensions {
    public static <T> void addOnCompare(List<T> collection, T item,
                                        Comparator<T> comparator) {
        synchronized(collection) {
            int i = 0;
            int size = collection.size();
            if (size == 1) {
                int diff = comparator.compare(item, collection.get(0));
                switch(diff) {
                case 1: i++; break;
                default: break;
                }
            } else {
                int range = size - 1;
                i = size / 2;
                int left = 0; 
                int right = range;
                while(true) {
                    if (i <= 0) { i = 0; break; }
                    if (i > range) { i = range; break; }
                    int diff = comparator.compare(item, collection.get(i));
                    if (diff == 0) break;
                    else { 
                        if (diff == -1) right = i;
                        if (diff == 1) left = i;
                        int near = i + diff; 
                        if (near < 0) { i = 0; break; }
                        if (near > range) { i = range + 1; break; }
                        int diff_near = comparator.compare(item, collection.get(near));
                        if (diff_near == 0) { i = diff_near; break; }
                        if (diff_near == diff) {
                            int step = (right-left)/2;
                            if (step == 0) step = 1;
                            switch(diff){
                            case -1:
                                right = i;
                                i = i - step; break;
                            case 1: 
                                left = i;
                                i = i + step; break;
                            }
                        } else if (diff > diff_near) { 
                            i = near; break; 
                        } else { break; }           
                    }
                }
            }
            collection.add(i, item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen Collections#binarySearch? [link to javadoc (Java 6)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Comment: A javadoc and/or some comments explaining the method's purpose would be very helpful.

Comment: Sorry, but that `synchronized` will only work if _all_ references to the passed-in collection are _also_ locked.  Also, it won't stop people from modifying the _contents_ of the collection, if it contains mutable classes.  If you really want threadsafety, you have to copy the collections, **and** the contents (or make things immutable).  Otherwise, I'd remove the synchronization, and document that the method isn't threadsafe.

Answer (score 3):

Parts this question have already been answered on StackOverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13529644/139985  So I'm going to treat this as a simple request for a code review.

1. The method name is opaque ... `addOnCompare` does not clearly imply a particular action ... and there is no javadoc for the method.  This immediately makes code-review hard ... because I have to try and figure out what the code is trying to do before I can comment on whether it is doing that well.
2. The parameter name `collection` is poor.  It is a list, not a collection.
3. The local variable `diff_near` should be `diffNear`.
4. This is convoluted:

   ```
           switch(diff) {
           case 1: i++; break;
           default: break;
           }
   ```

   Write it as:

   ```
           if (diff == 1) { i = 1; }
   ```
5. I don't know what these lines are trying to do, but they are definitely wrong:

   ```
           int near = i + diff; 
           if (near < 0) { i = 0; break; }
           if (near > range) { i = range + 1; break; }
           int diff_near = comparator.compare(item, collection.get(near));
   ```

   The value returned by a comparator has no meaning beyond being -ve, zero, or +ve.  So adding it to the index `i` is going to have an unpredictable effect. Indeed, since `range` never changes, this code makes the behaviour of the entire algorithm too difficult to understand.
6. I'm going to hazard a guess that the method is intended to insert `item` at the correct position in a previously sorted list.  But given the above, I have grave doubts that it will actually work for all possible (valid) comparators and all possible (sorted) input lists.
7. Even if this code did work, the performance for a linked list would be poor.  The `List.get(int)` method for a linked list is `O(N)`, so even an optimal binary search pattern would result in `O(Nlog(N))` operations to insert one element into the linked list.  A simple traversal of the list followed by an insert would be `O(N)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `java.util.TreeSet`. 
If and only if it needs to be threadsafe, use `Collections.synchronizedSortedSet()` to get a synchronized wrapper.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

your version, if it works correctly, has O(n) complexity. (as Stephen C already noted)

TreeSet has remove and contains, as well as add, all with O(log n)